# Multi collections order

Tags: android, collections

I have an object like this:

```
class User {
     String row;
     String tipo_ing;
     String name;
}
```

I use this code for create different order:
**order by tipo_ing**

```
Collections.sort(Ingred, new Comparator<User>(){
                                  public int compare(User emp1, User emp2) {
                                    return emp1.getTipoIng().compareToIgnoreCase(emp2.getTipoIng());
                                  }
                                });
```

is possible after create the first order by tipo_ing, create a "sub order" by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean by *sub order*:

> ordering the `Users` by `name` when `tipo_ing` is equal

then the answer is **yes**.

Since Java uses [*Mergesort*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) for sorting collections of `Object`s and this is a [*stable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) sorting algorithm, you can do this:

```
Collections.sort(users, BY_NAME);
Collections.sort(users, BY_TIPO_ING);
```

to achieve the following order:

```
tipo_ing name
X        Alice
X        Bob
Y        Eve
Y        Mallaroy
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `compare` method, simply check if both `typo_ing`s are the same. If they are, compare on their `name`:

```
public int compare(User emp1, User emp2) {

  int diff = emp1.getTipoIng().compareToIgnoreCase(emp2.getTipoIng());

  if (diff == 0) {
    return emp1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(emp2.getName());
  }

  return diff;
}
```